# How to Add text after checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" /> </label></td>
```

How can i insert text into the label, without losing  the checkbox?

Ive tried the following, but i lose the checkbox:

```
 $('.chkRootCauseSummary').click(function () {
    var num = $(this).closest('table').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    $(this).closest('label').append().html(num);
});
```

Comment: Use `.after` instead of `.append`

Comment: Otherweise move the checkbox outside the label

Comment: Hello, I tried using `.after` but I still lose the checkbox. Not sure if this is worth mentioning but I am devloping with IE10..

Comment: Don't use `.html()` it will replace all content of the label. Just use `.append(num);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is a [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) since it needs to be added inside `.checkbox-inline` and outside `.chkRootCauseSummary`

Replace

```
 $(this).closest('label').append().html(num);
```

with

```
 $(this).closest('label').prepend(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much cleaner way to do it. Simply, while creating your `checkbox` add a value attribute (or an attribute with any name)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chkRootCauseSummary" value="Some Value" />
```

and use CSS selector `:after` like

```
[type=checkbox]:after {
    content: attr(value);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand this. how does the `content : attr(value);` work?

Comment: put `attr(value)` ("Some Value", in this case) `:after` your `[type;checkbox]`. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$('.chkRootCauseSummary').click(function() {
  var num = $(this).closest('table').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
  $(this).closest('label').after(num)
});
```

Comment: Use stack snippets only if you have code that can run in the browser (have html and jQuery if you use them) adn 4 spaces or `{}` button if you have just code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.chkRootCauseSummary').click(function () {
    var num = $(this).closest('table').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    $(this).closest('label').after().html(num);
});
```

Comment: This will not work because `.html()` will replace all the content.

Comment: I see a 'prepend' answer. That should do.